# C - Char to hexa

Tags: c

I have str:

```
char *str = "lala";
```

Now, I would like convert any chars in str to hexadecimal, example:

```
str = convert(str);
print str: 0x6C 0x61 0x6C 0x61
            ^ l  ^ a  ^ l  ^ a
```

How I can do that ?

Answer (score 2):

```
char *convert(char const *str) {
    int len = strlen(str);
    char *retVal = (char *)malloc(5 * len);
    char *pos = retVal;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i, pos += 5) sprintf(pos, i? " 0x%x" : "0x%x", str[i]);
    retVal[5 * len - 1] = '\0';
    return retVal;
}
```

Might have missed something, haven't used C for eight years.

Answer (score 2):

Simply by asking printf to do it :

```
void convert(char* str, size_t length) {
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("0x%02x ", str[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using this implementation....

```
#define MAX 100

char *convert(char *str)
{
    char *hexStr = (char *)malloc(strnlen(str, MAX) * 5);
    if (hexStr == NULL)
         return NULL;
    int i,j;

    for (i=0, j=0; str[i]; j+=5,  i++)
        sprintf(hexStr + j, "0x%02x ", str[i]);

    hexStr[--j] = '\0';

    return hexStr;
}
```

Comment: Buffer overflow potential: `sprintf()` will write `0xNN \0`, so if the length is 2, then it will allocate 10 bytes, but it will write `0xNN 0xNN \0` (11 bytes). Other than that, nicely done :)

Comment: the for loop wouldn't write null character to the buffer. The statement hexStr[--j] = '\0'; write null character at the last space character. So, buffer overflow shouldn't occur.

Comment: The `sprintf()` function always writes a null character. From the C standard: _The `sprintf` function is equivalent to `fprintf`, except that the output is written into an array (specified by the arguments) rather than to a stream. A null character is written at the end of the characters written;..._ So when you write 5 characters to the buffer with `sprintf()`, you're also writing a 6th character at the end: the null character.

Answer (score -2):

```
char* x = str - 1;
while(*++x) printf("%02x ", (int) *x); // Print one character in hex
printf("\n") // Finish with a carriage return
```

Comment: This code has undefined behaviour. Pointer arithmetic is only valid *within* an array (including the one-past-the-end pointer). (Then again, I wish people just stopped using increment subexpressions just to show off that they "know C".)

Comment: Could have used `char* x = str; while(*x) printf("%02hhx ", *x++);` and avoid the initial `str - 1`.  `(int)` serve no purpose.

Comment: @KerrekSB In the question, `str` points to a character array. In my answer, `x` iterates over that array without changing `str`. `x` is not dereferenced at any time when it points outside the bounds of `str`.

Comment: `x = str - 1` is UB even without dereferencing.    "..  If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined...." C11dr §6.5.6 8

Comment: @chux That seems to be saying that `x == ((x - 1) + 1)` is not true. Within this context, `x` is not a pointer operand until _after_ its predecrement has been undone by `++`.